# error in visual studio 2010/ corruption of the heap

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, image-processing

I can compile my code but when I try to run it I get this error:

> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in .exe file or any of the DLLs it has loaded

I tried to debug it but it is strange that It does not matter where I put the breakpoint I get this error again :(

Does anyone know what is the problem?

After getting some suggestion, I cleaned the code and it worked but now I am struggling with a new memory allocation error:

```
#define CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT 3;
Mat Valv;
   if( sumValv[0] > sumValv[0]){
      vector<Vec3f> circles;
      HoughCircles( Valv, circles, 3 , 1, Valv.rows/8, 200, 100, 0, 0 );
}
```

I am working with opencv library and I am going to detect circles in the image by using HoughCircles function. 
I get error in the HoughCircles line...memory allocation error:(
I heve no idea what is the reason...

Comment: Please make sure all the program heap memory gets cleaned before exiting the program

Comment: In addition to the good advice that ComicSansMS gave, are you using any dlls in your application? If so make sure that they were all compiled with Visual Studio 2010 and you are not mixing Debug and Release. I mean its also bad to use a Release dll in a Debug application or vise versa.

Comment: @Subhajit: Thanks, I cleaned the code and it works now  :)

Comment: @user2758510 Note that if you really had a heap corruption, your changes might have just masked the problem. You should invest some time to assure that you don't have any invalid heap operations luring in your code.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: you are completely right..it seems that the problem is much bigger than that! I will reEdit my question.

Comment: Was opencv built with Visual Studio 2010? And also you are using a debug dll for opencv with your debug application correct?

Comment: @drescherjm: Yes, I debug dll files.

Answer (score 4):

The Debug runtime of Visual C++ inserts [special character sequences](http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html) between allocated memory blocks. If it detects that one of these magic patterns was overwritten, it reports this as a heap corruption.

The problem with these kinds of errors is that they are usually only detected some time after the actual corruption occurred. So the callstack that you get when the corruption is reported is likely to be unrelated to the actual problem.

Make sure you check your code for unconstrained memory access that could lead to an out of bounds write. Memory diagnostic tools like [AppVerifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) or [VTune](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe) can help hunting down the problem, but in general these errors are quite a pain to debug.